# Google Datastore Pagination

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I am trying to use the cursor to implement pagination but when I try to use the endCursor that is returned after my first query (queries 10 records), it gives me an error "invalid encoding". By the way I have a total of 16 records. I am expecting that on my next query, it will give me the last 6 records

Here's my code:

```
    router.get("/scan/history/query", async (req: Request, resp: Response) => {
        const userId = resp.locals.user && resp.locals.user.sub
        const pageCursor = req.query.cursor
        if (userId) {

            let mainQuery = dataStoreClient.createQuery(process.env.GOOGLE_DATASTORE_KIND_SCAN_RESULTS)
                .filter("userId", QUERY_FILTER_OPERATORS.EQUAL, userId)
                .filter("isDeletedDocument", QUERY_FILTER_OPERATORS.EQUAL, false)
                .select(["__key__", "scanDate", "scanKeyword", "scanFilter",
                    "hasRecord", "scanThreatStatus", "scanDuration",
                    "scanType", "scanStatus", "domainName"])
                .order("scanDate", { descending: true })
                .limit(10)
            if (pageCursor) {
                mainQuery = mainQuery.start(pageCursor)
            }
            const results = await mainQuery.run()
            const entities = results[0]
            const info = results[1]
            const hasNextPage = info.moreResults !== "NO_MORE_RESULTS"
            const pageResult = new PageResult(entities, info.endCursor, hasNextPage)
            return HttpResult.Ok(resp, pageResult)
        }
        return HttpResult.UriNotFound(resp)
    })
```

UPDATE:
I tried this with thousands of records and my limit is still 10. It works perfectly for like 2 or 3 queries but when I tried to query for the fourth time, it throws me an error "invalid encoding"

Comment: Can you edit your code to show how you are getting, storing and retrieving the pageCursor?

Comment: Currently for testing, I am returning the pageCursor along with the entities as api response. Then I use the pageCursor as query string for the next api call for the next records

Comment: You are not waiting for the query to complete before you are checking for then next pageCursor. The contents might be changing while you are reading it causing corruption of the value.

Comment: is using await differ from .then(function()) ?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but in case anyone else comes across this issue (as I just did), I was able to resolve it by encoding the cursor value using `encodeURIComponent()`. It looks like the cursor value occasionally contains a `+` character, which causes issues when not escaped in the URL